How can I get issues that created by GithubApp Bot by using REST API?
I want to get my repo's issues that created by my GithubApp Bot by using REST API. It means I don't want to get the issues only created by user.
I noticed that there is a list-repository-issues api, and there is a parameter called "creator". I guess maybe I can use it, so I tried it. But failed. Is there a way to achieve that? Here is my code:
async function getIssues(githubToken: string, page: number = 1) {
    const result = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        params: {
            labels: "label",
            per_page: 20,
            page: page,
        },
        url: `https://api.github.com/repos/nyanpasuspace/maoji/issues`,
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${githubToken}`,
            'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
        },
    });
    return result.data;
}


"there is a parameter called 'creator'. I guess maybe I can use it, so I tried it. But failed.": What failed? What error message was encountered? Please [edit] the question to include more information. Using the creator query parameter with your username returns expected results. What's the issue with using that parameter?
